# iOS app in simulator splash screen is rotated 90 degrees

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a default-landscape.png image with 480 width, 320 height that when displayed in my simulator, comes up rotated 90 degrees. I'm using the App Game Kit for my graphics engine, and standard C++ for the rest of it, but I'm fairly certain it's something to do with an xcode configuration. Here's an image of what I'm running into:

[image: http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y102/paultr/ScreenShot2012-12-23at114643PM_zpsb6761d90.png]

Comment: Did you check if you are supporting all the orientations in your Xcode? Go to Target settings and check if it supports all of the these UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. Also check the default landscape image name is `Default-Landscape.png` itself.

Comment: Im just supporting landscape right and left for my game. And that is the name of the file.

Comment: In that case check in target settings and make sure it has only landscape orientations selected.

Comment: Yup, only have landscape left and right selected.

Comment: http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y102/paultr/ScreenShot2012-12-24at122523AM_zpsfd822d3e.png Here's what my target screen looks like.

Comment: That looks fine for me. Make sure default image name is exactly as shown in my comments. Other than that I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the height be 480 and the width be 320 if you want the device to be in portrait mode? Anyway you could programmatically set the device orientation, you can try adding this to your AppDelegate to set the device orientation the way you want it to be `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, no I want the device to be in landscape. That aspect is working exactly like I wanted. It's that I have a default.png image set up in the proper ratio for landscape, but it's somehow being flipped like it's trying to be in portrait.

Comment: How about try turning the image 90 degrees to the left in photoshop or another image editing tool since xcode is turning it 90 degrees to the right and then building since then xcode would rotate the image the image would be in the orientation you want.

Comment: Xcode will automatically turn the image 90 degrees if you set the orientation to landscape, so create the image sideways so really the top of the image should be pointing to the left, and then when you run the app, xcode will flip the image for you and it should be how you expect it to look.